# Was genau ist einfache oder doppelte Übermacht?

Tags: meaning

> Nehmen wir zwei sich gegenüber stehende Heere, eines mit 100 Soldaten,
>   das andere mit 300 Soldaten. Stehen die 100 Soldaten dann einer
>   zweifachen Übermacht oder einer dreifachen Übermacht gegenüber?

Eine Übermacht ist lt. Duden eine "*in Anzahl oder Stärke (weit) überlegene Macht."*

Wäre jetzt das Verhältnis 100:300 eine dreifache Übermacht, dann würde für mich daraus folgen, dass 100:200 eine zweifache und 100:100 eine einfache Übermacht sein müsste. 100:100 ist aber zahlenmäßig gleich und von daher nicht überlegen.

Schlussfolgerung für mich: Bei 100:300 handelt es sich um eine zweifache Übermacht.

Andererseits gibt es aber auch die Auffassung, dass man einfach die Zahlen ins Verhältnis (sprich: dividiert) setzt und dann auf eine dreifache Übermacht kommt.

Was ist richtig oder gebräuchlicher, 100:300 als doppelte oder dreifache Übermacht?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na ja, das muss man natürlich nicht so sehen. Ihre Auslegung der Duden-Definition erscheint mir recht arbiträr. Nirgendwo wird behauptet, es handele sich um eine Maßeinheit. Wenn man die Definition für bare Münze nimmt, ist "Übermacht" einfach die mächtigere Seite - was uns nichts darüber verrät, was nun mit "doppelter Übermacht" gemeint sein mag.

Mit solchen Formalargumenten wird man letztlich nicht weit kommen. Der Sprachgebrauch wiederum ist relativ schwer zu ermitteln, weil oft kein weiterer Kontext gegeben wird, sodass man die genaue Intention des Sprechers nicht rekonstruieren kann. (Normalerweise ersetzt der mit der Angabe einer *n*-fachen Übermacht ja eben die genaue Niveauangabe.) Eine COSMAS-Abfrage (W-ohneWikipedia-öffentlich) nach `(doppelte* oder *fache*) /+w1 Übermacht` liefert insgesamt 174 Ergebnisse. In den wenigen Fällen, denen man aus den kurzen Auszügen eine bestimmte Interpretation erkennen kann, finde ich keinen Nachweis für die von Ihnen favorisierte Deutung gegenüber fünf oder sechs Nachweisen für die andere. Außerdem gibt es offenbar noch eine Art "Faktorinterpretation", deren Verbreitung ich aber einstweilen mit einem Fragezeichen versehen würde.

1. *n*-fache Übermacht i.S.v. das *n*-Fache:

   - *Doch sie sah sich einer 15fachen Übermacht ausgesetzt. Jeder Beklagte feuerte aus allen Rohren gegen die Klägerin (...) Die Tatbestands- und die Rechtsfragen, welche das Gericht für jede einzelne Partei (eine Klägerin und 15 Beklagte) (...)* (Neue Zürcher Zeitung, 04.09.2003)
   - *Die Ungarn reden gerne von einer "Heldenstadt", weil der dortige Burghauptmann Dobo anno 1551 mit nur 2000 Verteidigern die fünfzigfache Übermacht von 100.000 Türken abgewehrt hat.* (Oberösterreichische Nachrichten, 13.09.1997)
   - *Im Guerillakrieg hält das Pentagon eine zehnfache Übermacht für wünschenswert; demnach braucht der Feind, wann immer wir 100 000 Mann Verstärkung schicken, nur 10 000 Mann zu schicken, um das bisherige Verhältnis wiederherzustellen.* (Die Zeit, 10.02.1967)
   - *Unser Kontinent hatte zahlenmäßig mit 400 Millionen Menschen eine fast dreifache Übermacht gegenüber den islamischen Ländern mit 150 Millionen.* (Die Zeit (Online-Ausgabe), 11.04.2002)
   - *Sie haben nur einen Sitz weniger als die SPD, sind alleinige Opposition und sollen dennoch nur 25 Prozent der Grundredezeit erhalten (...) Die SPD wird die Argumente der CDU ja kaum derart fürchten, dass Rot-Grün gleich mit dreifacher Übermacht in den Ring steigen muss.* (Rhein-Zeitung, 16.05.2011) [Bezieht sich auf einen Artikel, in dem es heißt, "Die alleinige Oppositionspartei CDU fühlt sich massiv benachteiligt etwa beim Rederecht (...) [D]as Verhältnis von Regierung und Opposition wäre bei der Grundredezeit 3:1 für Rot-Grün."]
2. *n*-fache Übermacht i.S.v. um das *n*-Fache mehr:

   - (keine)
3. *n*-fache Übermacht i.S.v. über *n* Übermachtfaktoren verfügend (Faktorinterpretation):

   - *Als Folge dieser Szene musste Küsnacht 2 Minuten in Unterzahl antreten, und eine weitere Strafe führte zur doppelten Übermacht der Rheintaler (...)* (St. Galler Tagblatt, 20.10.2008)
   - *Was in den zwei Startdritteln nicht vorhanden war, klappt nun plötzlich: 4:3 bei doppelter Überzahl, 4:4 bei einfacher Übermacht, der SCR war erwacht.* (St. Galler Tagblatt, 09.02.2009)
   - *Der SC Rheintal ging sofort in die Offensive, aber auch eine doppelte Überzahl reichte nicht für die Führung. Besser war vorerst das Powerplay der Gäste, denn ihnen reichte eine einfache Übermacht fürs erste Tor (...)* (St. Galler Tagblatt, 08.02.2010)
   - *"Sie, die Sowjetunion, rüstet, um verteidigt zu sein. Diese Nuß, die ich vor Sie hinlege, stelle Ihre Rüstung dar. Wir fühlen uns dadurch bedroht. Ich lege eine weitere Nuß vor mich: das ist unsere Verteidigung gegen Sie. Die Chinesen, denke ich, reagieren wie andere Leute auch. Sie brauchen auch eine Nuß: hier lege ich sie hin. Nun fühlen Sie, die Sowjetunion, sich einer doppelten Übermacht gegenüber (...)"* (Die Zeit, 18.05.1979) [alternativ in Kategorie 1: 2 Nüsse vs. 1 Nuss als doppelte Übermacht]

Comment: Interessante Sache, das mit den Nüssen...

Comment: Warum sollen bei 2. die Regierungsparteien 100% der Redezeit und nicht 75% bekommen? 75% zu 25% wäre dann wieder das n-Fache und es fiele unter 1. Vielleicht zu 3. zählen könnte man Fälle wie *die spielerische und taktische Übermacht*, also eine Übermacht in zweierlei Hinsicht?

Comment: @DavidVogt Nicht 100% der Redezeit, sondern der Grundredezeit, was ich aktuell als Maßeinheit auffasse. Mein Gedanke war einfach, dass die von dir genannte Auslegung (die intuitiv zunächst auch meine war) unlogisch ist, weil dann ja niemand mehr sonst im Parlament reden dürfte. Ich schaue mal eben, ob ich den Artikel im Ganzen finde.

Comment: @DavidVogt Du hast Recht. Der Kommentar, aus dem das Zitat ist, bezieht sich auf einen anderen Artikel in derselben Ausgabe, aus dem hervorgeht, dass es überhaupt nur 3 Parteien im Landtag gab und "das Verhältnis von Regierung und Opposition [...] bei der Grundredezeit 3:1 für Rot-Grün [wäre]". Ich habe das eben korrigiert.

Answer (score 2):

Die Formulierung *n-fache Übermacht* ist eine - wenngleich umgangssprachlich verführerische, weil einigermaßen flüssig auszusprechende - schwammige Angabe, die man möglichst **vermeiden sollte**.
Ist *n* relativ groß, so spielt es praktisch keine Rolle (ob bei einer 20-fachen Übermacht die 100 Verteidiger sich nun 2.000 oder 2.100 Angreifern gegenüber sehen, dürfte weder für den Ausgang der Schlacht noch für den posthumen Ruhm der Verteidiger relevant sein).
Bei kleineren Verhältnissen benutzt jede mir bekannte ernstzunehmende Publikation aus dem militärhistorischen Bereich Angaben wie

> eine drei-zu-eins Übermacht
>   war im Verhältnis 5 zu 2 überlegen
>   übertraf den Gegner im Verhältnis 7 zu 5

Answer (score 0):

Wenn dem Wort [**Übermacht**](https://dwds.de/wb/%C3%9Cbermacht) eine Verhältnisangabe wie z.B. *dreifach* vorangestellt wird, so basiert diese Angabe auf realen **oder** geschätzten Mengen (Größen) aus denen eine Verhältniszahl berechnet wurde. Im einfachen Fall wie hier werden nur zwei Mengen miteinander verglichen.

Es sollte für den Anwendungsfall *n-fache Übermacht* immer der Quotient berechnet und dann (gerundet) angegeben werden:

```
120.000 Soldaten / 40.000 Soldaten = 3 => dreifache Übermacht [an Soldaten]
```

Der in der Frage genannten Schlussfolgerung kann ich so nicht folgen, da von der größeren Menge nicht einfach 40.000 [Soldaten] abgezogen werden dürfen.

> 40.000 Christen standen 120.000 Muslimen (und christlichen Sklavensoldaten) gegenüber, welche von Hadim Suleiman Pasha angeführt wurden. Eine **dreifache Übermacht** stand den europäischen Christen gegenüber.

Quelle Beispielsatz: [Vaslui – Polen, Ungarn und Moldavien gegen die Osmanen](https://younggerman.com/2016/01/09/1421/)